# Bash history - get last command by string, containing space

Tags: bash, shell

I know about the bash feature !text, which runs the last command starting with "text".
But it seems not to work, when "text" contains space. Sometimes it is useful to search for something, containing spaces.

for example:

```
history | grep ping
  514  ping 192.168.100.2
  515  ping 192.168.100.3
  516  ping 192.168.100.4
  517  ping google.com
  518  ping 192.168.100.5
  519  ping 192.168.100.6
  520  ping 192.168.100.7
```

I want to call the line "ping google.com", using the ! feature. I tried some things, but they failed:

this is the standard behavior, it runs the last ping command

```
/root# !ping  
ping 192.168.100.7
```

A simple string with space after ! does not work

```
/root# !ping google
ping 192.168.100.7 google
```

As I know, quotes tell bash to interpret a string with space as a single string, instead of 2 separate strings. But here it does not work as expected.

```
/root# !"ping google"
bash: !"ping: event not found

/root# !'ping google'
bash: !'ping: event not found

/root# "!ping google"
"ping 192.168.100.7 google google"

/root# '!ping google'
bash: !ping google: command not found

/root# !\"ping google\"
bash: !\"ping: event not found

/root# !(ping google) 
bash: !: event not found
```

This calls the command, but it will call the last command, containing the string. I want only commands, beginning with "ping"

```
/root# !?google
ping google.com
```

Is it possible to do what I want?

Comment: `!?ping google` (or even only `!?ping g`) would work. This would however also match `echo ping google.com`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use backward search (control-r if the edit mode is set to emacs, which is the default) and it works with space.

Answer (score 6):

I can think of a couple of ways:

1. Use `?`. The following is from `man history`:

   ```
   !?string[?]
         Refer to the most recent command preceding the
         current postition in the history list contain‐
         ing  string.  The trailing ? may be omitted if
         string is followed immediately by a newline.
   ```

   So, you should be able to do this:

   ```
    !?ping google?
   ```
2. Use the reverse search feature. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> ans start typing `ping google`. Hit enter when the relevant command has been found.